# How to reduce the file size of all the photos in a folder

Tags: image-processing

How to reduce the file size of each photo inside the folder. We want to keep the image dimension size of the photos and only reduce its file size.

Comment: Just reduce its quality, right? What image type?

Comment: I don't want to compress the files, I just want to reduce the file size of the images without touching the actual dimension. I don't care if the images quality is very low, I just want to preserve the images dimensions, compress all images and download it.